# How do I prove the correctness of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, bipartite, bellman-ford, proof-of-correctness

We are given the following algorithm:

Input: bipartite graph `G=(L,R,E)`, weight function `w:E->Z` and a source vertex `s in L`

Algorithm:

1) Define `E1={(u,v) in E | u in L, v in R}` and `E2=E\E1`

2) Initialize `d(s)=0` and `d(v)=inf` for all vertices in L and R (except s)

3) Perform `floor((|L|+|R|)/2)` times:

  a. Pass on all edges `(u,v) in E1`:

    if `d(v) > d(u) + w(u,v)` then `d(v) = d(u) + w(u,v)`

  b. Pass on all edges `(u,v) in E2`:

    if `d(v) > d(u) + w(u,v)` then `d(v) = d(u) + w(u,v)`

4) Return `d(v)` for each vertex

This algorithm gives the shortest path from `s` to all other vertices and we are asked to prove its correctness. Now, as much as I can tell, the correctness proof should be exactly like Bellman-Ford's algorithm (using induction over the path's length), but I can't tell what is the change I am suppose to do in order to make it work for this algorithm.

I am not sure if I can ask question like these on here, but I've been on this for the past 4 days and I can't seem to see any difference from bellman-ford's correctness proof.

Any suggestions?

Thank you :)

Comment: The Bellman--Ford proof doesn't go through as is because the number of rounds is half what B--F calls for.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yes I understand, but as I was studying, I noticed that I can use the correctness of BF in my favor here, cause this algorithm passes on the vertices as well.
Isn't there a way to adjust BF's proof for this one ?

Comment: There is. The short version is that (1) like B--F, this algorithm never underestimates vertex distances (2) every path of length at most n-1 appears as a subsequence of the sequence of arc relaxations performed by the algorithm, which ensures that the algorithm doesn't overestimate in the end. The rest is proving (2).

Comment: But isn't (2) exactly what BF does too ? The thing is that I have BF's proof in my papers but as I'm looking at this algorithm I feel like it's the same proof (despite having less iterations, I don't understand how this can affect the proof).

Comment: B--F has n-1 rounds and repeats every arc in every round, which makes it more or less trivial to find the subsequence. With floor(n/2) rounds, it's a little more difficult.

Comment: This is a *directed* bipartite graph, I guess?  Otherwise isn't E2 empty?

Comment: Assuming so, then you would have to prove that, because the graph is bipartite, each round of this algorithm is equivalent to *two* rounds in B-F.

Comment: @MattTimmermans it is directed, and maybe I understand what you mean. You're saying that I should mention that in each round, this algorithm passes on two different arcs whereas BF passes on one of them, which in the end makes them kinda equal ?